# Photos not appearing in RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2, flickr

I am trying to add flickr images with their titles in a recycler view the problem encountering me is that I want to pass the images and their titles to FlickrPhoto class in the loop (please take a look above to see what I'm saying ) if you notice this line photos.add(new FlickrPhoto(title,uri)); you will see that it inside loop in enqueue function which is at the background task , So I recognize that line doesn't executed .. but when I've tried after enqueue function it works for me but ofcourse for just one image because , I'm outside the loop. I've tried many solutions but all fails

Here is my PhotoListActivity

```
package com.example.karim.bluecrunch;

/**
 * Created by karim on 8/26/16.
 */
public class FlickrPhoto {
    String title , image ;
    public  FlickrPhoto(String title , String image )
    {
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

and here is my PhotosRecyclerViewAdapter

```
package com.example.karim.bluecrunch;
public class PhotosRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotosRecyclerViewAdapter.PhotoViewHolder> {

    List<FlickrPhoto> photos = Collections.emptyList();
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public PhotosRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context , List<FlickrPhoto> photos)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.photos = photos;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public PhotoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent,false);
        return new PhotoViewHolder(row);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PhotoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        FlickrPhoto photo = photos.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(photo.title);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(photo.image);
        Glide.with(context).load(uri).placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder).crossFade().into(holder.imageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return photos.size();
    }

    public class PhotoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;
        private ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.photoTitle);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flickrPhoto);
        }



    }
}
```

and here is my PhotosListActivity

```
package com.example.karim.bluecrunch;

public class PhotosListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<FlickrPhoto> photos ;
    ArrayList<String> photosTitles;
    ArrayList<String> photoURLS;
    String title;
    String uri;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photos_list);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.photo_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2));
        PhotosRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new PhotosRecyclerViewAdapter(this,getPhotos());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public List<FlickrPhoto> getPhotos()
    {

        photos = new ArrayList<>();

        final String API_KEY = "fdac2e9676991ac53b34651adab52518";
        final String METHOD = "flickr.photos.search";
        final String AUTH_TOKEN = "72157671978046542-6e266595ffed01f8";
        final String API_SIG = "58e08d365779a8f2e946a2b5320199e2";
        final String FORMAT = "json";
        final int CALL_BACK = 1;

        HandleRetrofit handleRetrofit = HandleRetrofit.retrofit.create(HandleRetrofit.class);
        Call<Photos> call = handleRetrofit.Photos(METHOD,API_KEY,FORMAT,CALL_BACK,AUTH_TOKEN,API_SIG);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Photos>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Photos> call, Response<Photos> response) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Status Code = " + response.code());
                PhotosRetrofit photosRetrofit = response.body().photos;
                for (int i = 0; i < photosRetrofit.getPhoto().size(); i++) {
                    uri="https://farm"+photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getFarm()+".staticflickr.com/"+
                            photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getServer()+"/"+
                            photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getId()+"_" +
                            photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getSecret()+".jpg";

                    title= photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getTitle();

                    photos.add(new FlickrPhoto(title,uri));


                    Log.w(">>>>>>>>>>>","https://farm"+photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getFarm()+".staticflickr.com/"+
                            photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getServer()+"/"+
                            photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getId()+"_" +
                            photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getSecret()+".jpg");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Photos> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(PhotosListActivity.this,"Error :"+t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.w("---___--- Error ",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    /*    Log.w("Hello",uri.toString());
        Log.w("Hello",title.toString());*/
        photos.add(new FlickrPhoto("karim","https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8450/29141814932_a62977990d.jpg"));
        return photos;
    }
}
```

All things works fine , but the main problem at this line in my Activity

```
photos.add(new FlickrPhoto(title,uri));
```

I think it can't be done in the background tasks because this line

```
photos.add(new FlickrPhoto("karim","https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8450/29141814932_a62977990d.jpg"));
```

works fine after the enqueue function , but I don't know how to do such a trick to solve this problem .

**EDIT**

Please note that The loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < photosRetrofit.getPhoto().size(); i++) 
{
uri="https://farm"... ;
title= ..;
 **photos.add(new FlickrPhoto(title,uri));**
 Log.w(">>>>>>>>>>>","https://farm"+photosRetrofit.getPhoto()‌​.get(i).getFarm()+".‌​staticflickr.com/"+p‌​hotosRetrofit.getPho‌​to().get(i).getServe‌​r()+"/"+photosRetrof‌​it.getPhoto().get(i)‌​.getId()+"_" +photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getSecret()+".jpg");
 }
```

doesn't skipped because , if you try to log either title or uri inside the loop it will shown successfully in Logcat . The main problem is that this line of code `photos.add(new FlickrPhoto(title,uri));` passes the data "title and uri " to the FlickrPhoto class's constructor and this operation is in the enqueue -> onResponse (Background task) and I don't know why it is not working

It is excepted to load data (Images & Titles ) into recycler view but Actually nothing happens and

I've tried a couple of things

First , before return photos () arrayList at the PhotosListActivity class I've tried to pass a fixed data to the FlickrPhoto class's Constructor And it works and images shown into recycler view

Second , I've tried to add a default constructor and setter , getter for title and image to FlickrPhoto class and initialize it on OnCreate function at PhotosListActivity class then on the enqueue I used my setter and getter and it works and load all data successfully but when I've try to run again everything gone ! :( , and I don't know why

doing setters and getters was like this 
FlickrPhoto.java class

```
package com.example.karim.bluecrunch;

/**
 * Created by karim on 8/26/16.
 */
public class FlickrPhoto {
    String title , image ;
    public FlickrPhoto(){}
    public  FlickrPhoto(String title , String image )
    {
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

and PostListActivity Class

```
package com.example.karim.bluecrunch;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.http.Url;

public class PhotosListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<FlickrPhoto> photos ;
    ArrayList<String> photosTitles;
    ArrayList<String> photoURLS;
    FlickrPhoto flickrPhoto ;
    String title;
    String uri;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photos_list);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.photo_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
        PhotosRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new PhotosRecyclerViewAdapter(this,getPhotos());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        flickrPhoto = new FlickrPhoto();



    }

    public List<FlickrPhoto> getPhotos()
    {

        photos = new ArrayList<>();

        final String API_KEY = "fdac2e9676991ac53b34651adab52518";
        final String METHOD = "flickr.photos.search";
        final String AUTH_TOKEN = "72157671978046542-6e266595ffed01f8";
        final String API_SIG = "58e08d365779a8f2e946a2b5320199e2";
        final String FORMAT = "json";
        final int CALL_BACK = 1;

        HandleRetrofit handleRetrofit = HandleRetrofit.retrofit.create(HandleRetrofit.class);
        Call<Photos> call = handleRetrofit.Photos(METHOD,API_KEY,FORMAT,CALL_BACK,AUTH_TOKEN,API_SIG);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Photos>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Photos> call, Response<Photos> response) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Status Code = " + response.code());
                PhotosRetrofit photosRetrofit = response.body().photos;
                //photosRetrofit.getPhoto().size()
                for (int i = 0; i < photosRetrofit.getPhoto().size(); i++) {
                    uri="https://farm"+photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getFarm()+".staticflickr.com/"+
                            photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getServer()+"/"+
                            photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getId()+"_" +
                            photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getSecret()+".jpg";

                    title= photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getTitle();

                    flickrPhoto.setImage(uri);
                    flickrPhoto.setTitle(title);

                    photos.add(new FlickrPhoto(flickrPhoto.getTitle(),flickrPhoto.getImage()));


                    Log.w("++++++++++++",photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getTitle());

                    Log.w(">>>>>>>>>>>","https://farm"+photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getFarm()+".staticflickr.com/"+
                            photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getServer()+"/"+
                            photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getId()+"_" +
                            photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getSecret()+".jpg");



                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Photos> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(PhotosListActivity.this,"Error :"+t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.w("---___--- Error ",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    /*    Log.w("Hello",uri.toString());
        Log.w("Hello",title.toString());*/
        photos.add(new FlickrPhoto("karim","https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8450/29141814932_a62977990d.jpg"));
        return photos;
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you encountering? What are you trying to do that you don't know how to do?

Comment: I am trying to add flickr images with their titles in a recycler view 
the problem encountering me is that I want to pass the images and their titles to FlickrPhoto class in the loop (please take a look above to see what I'm saying ) 
if you notice this line `photos.add(new FlickrPhoto(title,uri));` 
you will see that it inside loop in enqueue function which is at the background task , So I recognize that line doesn't executed .. but when I've tried after enqueue function it works for me but ofcourse for just one image because , I'm outside the loop.
I've tried many solutions but all fails

Comment: Please edit your original question with these details. It will help if explicitly show what loop you are referring to so that potential answers don't have to take the extra time to search for it.

Comment: It sounds like you need to determine why the line inside the loop doesn't execute. Is `onResponse()` ever called at all? If it is, how many times does the loop iterate?

Comment: Oh , sorry for that 
The loop doesn't skipped because , if you try to log either title or uri inside the loop it will shown successfully in Logcat . 
The main problem is that this line of code `photos.add(new FlickrPhoto(title,uri));` passes the data "title and uri " to the FlickrPhoto class's constructor and this operation is in the enqueue -> onResponse (Background task) and I don't know why it is not working

Comment: The loop I'm referring is this : `for (int i = 0; i < photosRetrofit.getPhoto().size(); i++) { 
uri="https://farm"...
 title= ..
 **photos.add(new FlickrPhoto(title,uri));**            Log.w(">>>>>>>>>>>","https://farm"+photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getFarm()+".staticflickr.com/"+photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getServer()+"/"+photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getId()+"_" +photosRetrofit.getPhoto().get(i).getSecret()+".jpg");
}
`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "not working". What happens when you run your app? How does this behavior differ from what you want?

Comment: One more time...please edit your original question.

Comment: It is excepted to load data (Images & Titles ) into recycler view 
but Actually nothing happens.

Comment: I've tried a couple of things 
First , before return photos () arrayList at the PhotosListActivity class 
I've tried to pass a fixed data to the FlickrPhoto class's Constructor 
And it works and images shown into recycler view
Second , I've tried to add a default constructor and setter , getter for title and image to FlickrPhoto class and initialize it on OnCreate function at PhotosListActivity class then on the enqueue I used my setter and getter and it works and load all data successfully but when I've try to run again everything gone ! :(  , and I don't know why .

Comment: Original question Edited , sorry again for that

Comment: The edit is not enough. Almost everything you have posted in comments should be edited into your question to help us understand what you are trying to do. If you have changed your code, you need to include that in your edits.

Comment: Are you trying to show the photos in a RecyclerView? I'm guessing that they don't show up after the loop executes. Is that correct? Most likely you need to call [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) on your adapter.

Comment: Thank you very much for ur help , I'm really appreciate your time 
Sorry , about the question's bad description (but , now it's updated with full details) 
NOW , Finally my  problem has been solved , Thank u again ! :) 
@Code-Apprentice

Comment: What did you do to solve the problem? Feel free to add an answer to this question so that your work may help others with similar problems in the future.

Comment: I've removed the getters&setters and back again to my line 
`photos.add(new FlickrPhoto(title,uri));`
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
but with the notifyData to my adapter ;)

Comment: For future reference, when asking a question here you should post exactly what the problem is. In this case, something like "The picture does not appear in the recycler view" would have helped us understand exactly what your problem is with a lot less words than you have typed so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `RecyclerView` does not automatically update after adding elements to the array list with its data. You need to call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) on your adapter to force this update.